# Find the Laurent series expansion of the following function and hence find the integral over the unit circle centred at i

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, laurent-series

We are going to be examined on using the Laurent series expansion to find integrals along simple closed curves. But the notes and lectures barely covered it and we only have 2 examples given.

Can someone explain how to solve a question like this:

---

Determine the Laurent series expansion of

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}$$
about $z_0=i$, that is valid in the region $0<|z-i|<2$ and hence evaluate

$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{1+z^2}dz$$

where $\gamma(t)=i+e^{it}, 0\leq t\leq2\pi$

---

EDIT:

So is $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^2}=-\frac{1}{2i}.\frac{1}{z+i}+\frac{1}{2i}.\frac{1}{z-i}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2i}.\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{1}{2i}.\left(1-\frac{z-i}{2i}+\frac{{(z-i)}^2}{(2i)^2}...\right)$$

The Laurent series expansion.

And since this function has a single pole $i$ inside the circle, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-i}$ is the residue? So Res=$\frac{1}{2i}$

Comment: Hint: Note that $1+z^2=(1+iz)(1-iz)$. By other hand, partial fractions can be usefull.

Comment: @DiegoMath hints arent very useful as I have no idea what's going on in this question. I already know how to use Cauchy's Integral formula to find integral of the two partial fractions which add together to give the original fraction. But I want to use the Laurent series expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a partial fraction decomposition : $\frac1{z^2+1}=\frac1{(z+i)(z-i)}=-\frac1{2i}(\frac1{z+i}-\frac1{z-i})$.

Then use the geometric series to get the Laurent series:
$\frac1{z+i}=\frac1{z-i+2i}=\frac1{2i}(\frac1{1+\frac {z-i}{2i}})=\frac1{2i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-\frac {z-i}{2i} )^n$. 
 This converges for $\mid z-i\mid\lt 2$.

So:  $\frac1{2i}(\frac1{z-i}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-\frac {z-i}{2i} )^n)$ is the Laurent series centered at $i$.

Now use the residue theorem (the residue is $\frac1{2i}$) to compute the integral.

Comment: I edited the question, can you please have a quick look to see if I understood correctly? And thanks alot for that answer.

Comment: I think you have it.   Except we lost a minus sign.

Comment: Why did you expand the 1/z+i and not 1/z-i instead?Is it because we already know the coefficient of (z-i)^-1 in 1/z-i but not in 1/z+i?

Comment: The latter is already in the right form.   We want to expand about $i$.  So we want powers of $(z-i)$.

Comment: Ok. Sorry but I have another question. For 1/[(z+1)(z+3)] if we want a Laurent expansion valid for 1<|z|<3. How would I need to expand that? I can do the work myself but what should I turn this into? It seems this has two poles.

Comment: It does.  You can get a Laurent series on that annulus by mimicking the above.  First partial fractions,  then geometric series...etc.

Comment: So do we want to find the coefficients of 1/z? I will get 1/2[(1/1+z)-(1/3+z)]=1/2[(1-z+z^2...)-1/3(1-z/3+z^2/9...)]. Basically expand 1/1+z and 1/3+z using geometric series with r=-z in the first and r=-z/3 in the second?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92593/discussion-between-chris-custer-and-mohamad-moustafa).

Answer (score 0):

observe that $z^2+1=(z-i)^2+2i(z-i)$.
You can then look for the laurent series of $\frac{1}{y^2+2iy}$ about $y=0$.

You can show that $\frac{1}{(2iy)(1+\frac{y}{2i})}=\frac{1}{2iy}(1+\frac{y}{2i})^{-1}=\frac{1}{2iy}(1-\frac{y}{2i}+O(y^2))=\frac{1}{2iy}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}iy+O(y^2).$

Now switch $y$ and $z-i$, you get: $\frac{-i}{2(z-i)}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i(z-i)}{8}+O(z^2).$

You can now find the residue, as it corresponds to the coefficients of $(z-i)^{-1}$. You might want to use Cauchy-integral formula as a sense check at the end.

Comment: what's O(y^2)? I think we are supposed to use binomial and Taylor expansions to find the Laurent series expansion.

Comment: $O(y^2)$ just means all terms where the power of y is greater than or equal to 2. if it confuses you then you might want to replace it with ... (dot,dot,dot). I've used nothing more than the expansion $(1+x)^-1=1-x+x^2+....$ I guess that should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function $f(z)$ that has two poles, $z=\pm i$, why? because you can write your function as:
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}
$$

If we restrict ourselves to the domain consisting of the circle of radius $1$ centered at $i$ then your function can be writen as:
$$
f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z-i}
$$

where $g(z)=\frac{1}{z+i}$ is an analitic function in that domain and so admits a taylor series of the form:
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-i)^n
$$

and so the Laurent series of $f$ can be expresed as:

$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-i)^{n-1}
$$ 
where the $a_n$ are the coefficients from the Taylor series of the function $g$.

This coefficients can be computed as any other Taylor series:
$$a_0 = g(i) = \frac{1}{2i}$$
$$a_n = \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^ng(i)}{dz^n}$$

that is, near $z=i$ the function $g$ can be expanded as

$$ 
g(z) = \frac{1}{2i} + \frac{1}{4}(z-i)+\dots
$$

and so the function $f$

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2i(z-i)} + \frac{1}{4}+\dots
$$

If we now want to compute the integral of $f$ around $\gamma$ we have that:

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z =\int_\gamma \left(\frac{1}{2i(z-i)} + \frac{1}{4}+\dots\right)\mathrm{d}z = \int_\gamma \frac{1}{2i(z-i)}\mathrm{d}z + \int_\gamma\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{d}z+\dots =\frac{1}{2i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{(z-i)}\mathrm{d}z 
$$

as all the other integrands are analitic in the whole circle so a closed intregal vanishes.  This result could also be writen from the begining taking into account that $g$ is analitic as:

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z =\int_\gamma \frac{g(z)}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z=g(i)\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z 
$$

Finally taking into account that
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z = \int_{\mathrm{B}_1(0)} \frac{1}{z}\mathrm{d}z=2\pi i 
$$

We have that

$$ 
\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i g(i)= \frac{2\pi i}{2i} = \pi
$$